# Retrieving Unread Emails with EWS C#

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices

Below is my working code snippet that retrieves unread emails from custom folder names under Inbox.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder folder in findFolderResults.Folders)
{
    LogFile.AppendLog(folder.DisplayName + " folder found in Inbox.");
    if (folder.DisplayName == folderName)
    {
        LogFile.AppendLog(folder.DisplayName + " matches " + folderName);
        ItemView view = new ItemView(emailBatch);

        do
        {
            LogFile.AppendLog("Checking for unread emails in folder " + folder.DisplayName);
            emailItemList = service.FindItems(folder.Id, sf, view);
            foreach (var emailItem in emailItemList.Items)
            {
                LogFile.AppendLog("Getting unread emails in folder " + folder.DisplayName);
                EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, emailItem.Id);
                retrievedEmailList.Add((EmailMessage)email);
            }

            if (!emailItemList.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
                break;
        }
        while (emailItemList.MoreAvailable);
    }
}
```

There is a variable `emailBatch` that is currently being configured as `10`.

I do understand that this means that it will only check and retrieve `10` unread email at one go.
However, once the `10` email has been added to the list, will it continue to check for unread email?

I would need to add all unread emails to `retrievedEmailList`, instead of just 10 emails, if it happens.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [paged searching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633698(v%3Dexchg.80)). You seem to have partially tried this but your code is missing some stuff. I have updated your code and put comments in explaining the new code I've added.

```
// Set the offset for the paged search.
int offset = 0;
// Set the flag that indicates whether to continue iterating through additional pages.
bool MoreItems = true;

LogFile.AppendLog(folder.DisplayName + " folder found in Inbox.");
if (folder.DisplayName == folderName)
{
    // Continue paging while there are more items to page.
    while (MoreItems)
    {
        LogFile.AppendLog(folder.DisplayName + " matches " + folderName);
        // Set the ItemView with the page size and offset.
        ItemView view = new ItemView(emailBatch, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);

        LogFile.AppendLog("Checking for unread emails in folder " + folder.DisplayName);
        emailItemList = service.FindItems(folder.Id, sf, view);
        foreach (var emailItem in emailItemList.Items)
        {
            LogFile.AppendLog("Getting unread emails in folder " + folder.DisplayName);
            EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, emailItem.Id);
            retrievedEmailList.Add((EmailMessage)email);
        }

        // Set the flag to discontinue paging.
        if (!emailItemList.MoreAvailable)
            MoreItems = false;
        // Update the offset if there are more items to page.
        if (MoreItems)
            offset += pageSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information above. However, I encountered an error that says `ItemView does not contain a constructor that takes in 4 arguments`

Comment: The error is occurring because you seem to already have a `PageSize` variable and it's named `emailBatch`, which I hadn't catered for. I have updated the code.